# CSS : Add Width To Existing Width

Tags: css

I Need To add width to Existing Width. as an Example :

```
div.lists-container h4{
width: fit-content + 15px;
border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

so the width of the element is relative to its content but added 15px or so

Comment: You could use `padding` (left or right) along with `box-sizing: content-box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add 15px as padding or use the calc or min function

padding solution

```
div.lists-container h4{
  width: fit-content ;
  padding-inline: 7.5px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

you can not use fit-content in the calc function

min function

```
div.lists-container h4{
  width: min(100px, 250px);
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}
```

Comment: yep, i tried the calc function with fit-content and it didn't work but padding is working fine. thank you

Comment: you are more than welcome